# Chemical potential terms in Hamiltonian

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, chemical-potential, mean-field-theory

In the derivation of grand canonical ensemble, which assumes that the physical system (with Hamiltonian $H$) has an average energy $E$ and an average number of particles $\bar{N}$, the density matrix operator is given by

$$
\rho = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta(H - \mu N)}
$$

where $Z = tr e^{-\beta(H - \mu N)}$ is the grand canonical partition function, and $N$ is the particle number operator. The chemical potential $\mu$ is introduced as a Lagrange multiplier. It looks like that the average particle number constraint effectively changes the Hamiltonian to

$$
H \to H - \mu N
$$

However, in many mean field theory with an average particle number constraint (such as those related to spin liquids; see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/469341/222821) Phys.SE question), the constraint in imposed by changing the Hamiltonian to

$$
H \to H - \mu(N - \bar{N})
$$

For example, in Chapter 9 of Wen Xiao-Gang's book *Quantum Field Theory of Many-Body Systems*, the slave fermion mean field Hamiltonian of a spin liquid is

$$
H_{\text{mean}} = (\cdots) + \sum_i a_0(i) (f^\dagger_{i\alpha} f_{i\alpha} - 1)
\tag{9.1.6}
$$

The $(\cdots)$ part comes from mean field decoupling of the original Hamiltonian, and the last term is the chemical potential term imposing the constraint

$$
\langle f^\dagger_{i\alpha} f_{i\alpha} \rangle = 1
\tag{9.1.5}
$$

**Question**: Why is the extra $\mu \bar{N}$ term?